# Long running global timer in php

Tags: php, timer, cron

In my application I have multiple not realtime "games". In each game, each player has a score. During the course of the game, players may take turns doing some action.

However, if no actions are taken within a customizable amount of time (anywhere from 1 hour to 1 month), then both players will lose x amount of points.

I thought to have a global "timer" that is called by a cron job. At an interval of 1 hour, the timer will call each game's `deductPoints()` function.

Within the `deductPoints()` function I will do something like this:

```
deductPoints()
{
   timeSinceLastDeduction++;
   if(timeSinceLastDeduction >= frequencyOfDeduction)
   {
       deduct();
       timeSinceLastDeduction = 0;
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you storing this data in a relational database of some sort?

Comment: Yes. This hasn't been implemented yet, but in my current design I was thinking of using a sql database for state permanence.

Comment: You might want to consider a method of updating points in a single query rather than having to instantiate a potentially large number of objects for a single method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to store more data, I would suggest this design.

Instead of deducting the points every time (relying strongly on the "state" of the game), instead, store every action that the players have taken. Ex, lets take this table:

```
 id | playerid | action   |         stamp
----+----------+----------+------------------------
  1 |        1 | e2 to e4 | 2011-10-27 04:00:00-04
  2 |        1 |          | 2011-10-27 04:30:00-04
  3 |        1 |          | 2011-10-27 06:00:00-04
  4 |        1 |          | 2011-10-27 07:45:00-04
  5 |        1 |          | 2011-10-27 08:00:00-04
```

Etc. etc.

e2 to e4 is a Chess move by the way, one of the common opening moves. Your game, I can't really design that. The "action" is optional however, you only really need to store the fact that an action occured to calculate the penalty. (But might as well store extra information, as long as you have the space to do so of course).

"id" is the surrogate key in this case. In Postgresql, the DDL would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE actions(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  playerid int,
  action text,
  stamp timestamptz,
  UNIQUE(playerid, stamp));
```

The tuple (playerid,stamp) will be the "real" primary key. "id" is the surrogate key.

To see the difference in timestamps, the code is relatively simple using window functions. (Continuing to use PostgreSQL)

```
select playerid, time_between, id FROM
        (SELECT playerid,
                stamp - lag(stamp) OVER () as time_between,
                id FROM actions
                ORDER BY stamp)
                as ss
        WHERE playerid = 1
                AND time_between > '1 hour';
```

Sample Output, given the test data from earlier:

```
 playerid | time_between | id
----------+--------------+----
        1 | 01:30:00     |  3
        1 | 01:45:00     |  4
```

You don't have cron jobs at all. You stored more data (so it will be easier to "undo" actions). Your players can review past moves if they want to. If calculating the penalty becomes inefficient, then you can always just cache the score at a higher level.

Window Functions are not available in MySQL btw. But are available in PostgreSQL, SQL Server and Oracle.

EDIT: If space is a concern, then you can always "garbage collect" this table regularly. Still, that'd be a lot of games. Each row takes up ~48 bytes (assuming a null "action"). If you had 1000 players, each playing 200 games with 40 actions, you'd only have ~384MB of data.

Comment: Very cool, I can't believe I haven't run into window functions before. I'll look into this.

Comment: If you did need to do this with MySQL, or any other database without windowing functions, it would be easy to just return all of the actions for a player from a given game. Then you calculate it in your application code. Don't be ashamed of application code doing data-analysis. Its a neat trick that you can accomplish all of this in SQL, but don't focus on doing it if you don't have to.

Comment: Yeah, I have to use mysql, so I am basically doing this in application code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When a turn changes, just store the current timestamp into the database and then use cron to execute a check during certain interval and if the required amount of time has passed, perform your game functions.

Basically just like you visioned but you need to store the time values somewhere. Into a database or into a file.

Comment: Cool, I'm curious if there's a more efficient way to go about this though. In this scheme, say I have 1000 games, that means I have to "wake up" all 1000 games every hour even if only a couple of them are set to do things hourly

Comment: If you have 1000 similar games, you run one script from cron, which checks which games need attention and handles their functionality.